# Include a static page on other static page in play framework

Tags: java, html, playframework-2.0

I am using play framework for Java and working on a job portal project which contains the main site and with an admin panel. The main site and admin panel have different header and footer so I can't specify the header and footer in main as this would then be common for main site and admin panel.

So my main.scala.html looks like

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Job Portal</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body >
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

Which contains only the content part.

**I want to include header and footer (created in different static files) for main site in index.html. How can I do so in play framework for Java?**

Is there any other approach which can solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume that all your templates are located in the *views* directory.

Create another template, for example *footer.scala.html* with your desired content

**footer.scala.html**

```
@()
<div>This is foooter!</div>
```

Then in your *main.scala.html* you can include it by putting this line of code in it:

```
@views.html.footer()
```

The same goes with header or whatever you fancy.

This is [*referenced in docs*](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaTemplateUseCases) as **Includes** (you can use also tags if you prefer), also keep in mind that you can pass parameters into included views/tags

Comment: Don't forget that you can have multiple versions of main - so you might have adminMain.scala.html which is used by admin views, and publicMain.scala.html which is used by your non-admin views.

Comment: @SteveChaloner but where can i specify that admin views should use adminMain.scala.html and public views should use publicMain.scala.html

Comment: At the moment, your views contain `@main(parameters) {content}` - this is just a Scala function.   Once you have created, say, adminMain.scala.html you would use `@adminMain(parameters) {content}` instead. NB You may need to import it, depending on where you locate the file.

Comment: Incidentally, these are not static pages.